# How do you dynamically allocate space for a string array instance variable?

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a simple shell program using c++. I have a CommandLine class with instance variables for the number of arguments and an array of those arguments.

```
private:
int argc;
char *argv[];
```

Here is the code for the definition of my constructor in my CommandLine class:

```
 CommandLine::CommandLine(istream& in) {    
    string cmd;
    getline(in, cmd);
    vector<string> args;
    string arg;
    istringstream iss(cmd);
    while( iss >> arg ) args.push_back(arg);
    argc = args.size();
    argv = (char*) malloc(argc*sizeof(argv));
    }
```

When I try to compile, I get this error message:

CommandLine.cpp: In constructor ‘CommandLine::CommandLine(std::istream&)’:
CommandLine.cpp:29:41: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char*’ to ‘char* [0]’

Comment: Also, line 29 is the last line in the constructor, i.e. "argv = (char*) malloc(argc*sizeof(argv));"

Comment: `char *argv[];`  This is non-standard C++.  Arrays must be declared using a compile time expression, not left empty.  You could simply have used `std::vector<char *>` instead, then the line giving you the issue would be `argv.resize(argc);` instead of `malloc`

Comment: while we're at it: `std::vector<std::string>`…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your member definition from:

`char *argv[];`

to

`char** argv;`

For your task, they will be functionally compatible. Then, allocate space this way:

```
argc = args.size();
argv = (char**)malloc(argc * sizeof(char*));

if(!args.empty())
{
  for(int n = 0; n < argc; ++n)
  {
    const string& src = args[n];
    char*& current = argv[n];

    current = (char*)malloc((src.length() + 1) * sizeof(char));
    memcpy(current, src.c_str(), (src.length() + 1) * sizeof(char));
  }
}
```

However, I do not understand why you cannot use member of type `std::vector<string>`, since you already use it to temporarily store command line parameters. That would be much better solution (and less error-prone).

Comment: When I make the changes you suggest and use the code from above, I get these error messages:

CommandLine.cpp: In constructor ‘CommandLine::CommandLine(std::istream&)’:

CommandLine.cpp:23:44: error: incompatible types in assignment of ‘char**’ to ‘char** [0]’

CommandLine.cpp:30:26: error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘char*&’ from expression of type ‘char**’

Comment: These errors mean, that you didn't updated your code properly. If `argv[n]` is detected to be of type `char**`, `argv` member must have been declared as `char** argv[]`. It needs to be `char** argv` (without the brackets).

Comment: Thanks, that did it! Forgot that simple fix

Answer (score 0):

you should use: `char **argv;`

and allocate as follows:

```
argv = new char*[argc]; //needed to be deleted at destructor
for (int i=0; i< argc; i++){
   argv[i]= strdup(args[i].c_str()); //needed to be freed at destructor
}
```

A better solution is to use the `vector<string> args;` as member instead of `argv`.

Answer (score 0):

The idea of using `malloc` or `new` to create the `argv*` array is a messy approach that can lead to memory leaks.

An approach that will be free of memory leaks or direct allocation of memory using `malloc` or `new` would be this:

First, store both a vector of character arrays, and a vector of pointers to char:

```
class CommandLine
{
    typedef std::vector<char> CharArray;
    typedef std::vector<CharArray> ArgumentVector;
    ArgumentVector argvVec;
    std::vector<char *> argv;
    public:
        CommandLine(std::stream& in);
};
```

It is the `argv` vector that will ultimately hold the `char *` that are required for the command-line arguments.  The reason for the other `ArgumentVector` member is to ensure that those strings do not go out of scope (as long as the `CommandLine` object is alive).

Once you have this, then the function to place the arguments in the `argv` vector becomes more safe:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
//...
using namespace std;

void my_command_line(int numArgs, char** args);

CommandLine::CommandLine(std::istream& in)
{
    string cmd;
    getline(in, cmd);
    string arg;
    istringstream iss(cmd);
    while (iss >> arg)
    {
        // create an entry in our string vector.  This basically 
        // replaces the call to allocate for each new string
        argvVec.push_back(CharArray(arg.begin(), arg.end()));

       // make sure we null-terminate the last string we added.
        argvVec.back().push_back(0);

        // add the pointer to this string to the argv vector
        argv.push_back(argvVec.back().data());
    }

    // call the alternate command-line function
    my_command_line(argv.size(), argv.data());
}

void my_command_line(int numArgs, char** args);
{
    for (int i = 0; i < numArgs; ++i)
        std::cout << "argument " << i << ": " << args[i] << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    ifstream ifs("Test.txt");
    CommandLine test(ifs);
}
```

Note that there are no calls to `malloc`, no calls to `new`, no memory leaks, etc.  The only drawback is that you need two vectors, one for the string data, and another that holds the pointers to each of the string items, the latter being for the `char**` type required for a "main-like" function (in the example above, the "main" function simply prints out the argument list it was given).

Now, when the `CommandLine` object goes out of scope, all the elements are cleaned up since strings and pointers are stored in vectors.  No memory leaks, no pointers to mismanage, etc.

Live Example: http://ideone.com/0tCfYa